# Why is my brush stroke lighter than the same fill color?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, stroke, brush

[image]

I created a stroke with a brush but the color appears lighter than the color in the fill. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've created a blue brush. You must create it 100% black and when you paint with the brush, choose the color that corresponds.

This is the process:

- Make a shape: **100% Black**
- Select this shape and create a brush
- At **Colorization Method** choose **Tint**

[image]

- Choose a stroke color, fill=none
- Select the new brush and paint

---

To edit an existing brush, drag the brush from the Brush Panel to the artboard, edit it and create a new brush

[image: New brush]

Comment: It's a brush came with Adobe illustrator and yes It's grey not black, is there a way to edit it or fix the stroke itself.